# Plot bar chart with facet wrap

Tags: ggplot2, geom-bar, facet-wrap

I'm very new to R and struggling in plotting geom_bar with facet_wrap. I need to manually adding colors to the chart but I can't be able to. I can only add "fill = percentage" to be able to add colors but it's scaled from low to high which I don't want to. I want to manually set two colors
"#554F66", "#C2D1A4" on the chart. The chart only has 2 cols that represent 2 years.
I tried to use scale_fill_manual and scale_color_manual as well but it didn't work. :(

Below are my codes,can you please help? Thank you and much appreciate

```
ggplot(newdata2,aes(x=as.factor(CODE), y=percentage)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "#554F66")+
  facet_wrap(~variable) +
  theme_bw() +
  xlab("")
```

Answer (score 0):

it would be very helpful if you could post a reproducible example, with a data set that resembles yours, to help us understand what exactly the problem is.

See some code below that might help you:

```
ggplot(newdata2,aes(x=as.factor(CODE), y=percentage, fill = percentage)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  facet_wrap(~variable) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#554F66", "#C2D1A4")) +
  theme_bw() +
  xlab("")
```

Make sure that you use `scale_fill_manual()` when using the fill aesthetic.

Comment: It gives me an Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale

Comment: What kind of data is in your "percentage" column? You can try to something like that: `ggplot(newdata2 %>% mutate(percentage = as.factor(percentage), aes(x=as.factor(CODE), y=percentage, fill = percentage))` for you first line.